# Separating intranet CRUD/admin panel from production app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux

Working on a moderately complex react app using redux. We currently have a version we are satisfied with in production and are working on an administrative area for a version of the application that runs locally. This local version will have some basic CRUD functionality. I am currently evaluating the best way to keep the CRUD stuff out of the production build.

I'm most comfortable with just having a Makefile that has `sed` remove what I don't want in my production build. e.g. any admin routes, reducer additions, etc. But I feel like there is a better way. Possibly something I came across in a boiler plate from this time last year as I poured through dozens to get a feel for how things worked. Maybe it was in a webpack config? I cannot recall.

---

Lets take a simplified example.

1. In redux I have a document module.
2. This module I can CRUD a document. But in production I just want to Read the info. To shed package size I don't need to create, update, or delete. That only needs to occur in the version that runs on the local intranet.

at this point I am unsure how to proceed

---

My options feel limited

1. Create two branches. And meticulously merge any new production features into my local branch (far from ideal)
2. create two document modules (`document_read`, `document_admin`), only for reading, and the other for the rest.

   - have a webpack config that ignores this module at build time
   - have a second `combineReducers` function that runs this local version that adds in the `document_admin` module
   - conditionally add the admin component in the document container
   - have a second routes (react-router) file || conditionally add any routes related to document_admin, or perhaps as future module that allows a manger to review work done by users before submitting to production.
3. ??

at this point two seems like the clear winner. I just cannot help but feel like I am missing an incredibly obvious solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say go with two different webpack configs to only pack necessary resources for each application.

Another option (if you like to have it far more separated) would be to use git submodules (presumably you're using git and not other vcs), where you'd have two repositories, one for each app, sharing some core code (third repo, linked from both "app" repositories as submodule).

Comment: I noticed I never accepted an answer to this question. While I did not use your approach I appreciate you trying to answer my question. I went with what I was most comfortable with. I  have a Make file that will configure things as needed with a little shell scripting.